# Filtering for a group by with avg aggregate value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks like:

```
Order Number |       Item  |    Price  | Total
 555            Apple             2     10
 555            Orange Juice      3     10
 555            Water             1     10
 555            AppleJuice        4     10
 444            WaterMellonJuice  5     13
 444            Bread             8     13
```

I want to calculate the avg price of all orders that contain any juice in them as an item, 
so the avg of all order totals ( total is the same for the entire order ) but can have the word Juice in it ( it can be any type of juice )

How can I alter my code to account for this as well?

I have code such as

```
df[df.Item.str.contains('juice|Juice')]
```

that gives me all rows that contain the word juice in them but I want to tweak code to give me the avg total amount for all orders that contain the word Juice.

Note: The total is the same total for each row in each order that I do not want to count more than once, for example for order 555 the total is $33 and I only want to take that amount as one number when I avg all orders that have Juice or juice at least once in the order.

Desired output would be the avg total for all orders that contain at least Juice or juice once in the order

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, try `df[df.Item.str.contains('juice|Juice')].groupby('Order Number')['Total'].mean()`

Comment: Can you add exected output DataFrame?

Answer (score 1):

You can try pandas [contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html).

```
df.loc[df['Item'].str.contains('juice', case=False, regex=False), 'Total'].mean()
```